# matplotlib plotting the wrong indices

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot both a line plot and scatter plot on the same figure. The scatter plot looks great, but the line is plotted at the incorrect indices. That is, the scatter plot data is along the correct indices, [0,4621], but the line plot is "bunched up" into indices [3750,4621].

```
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(ii, values,
    color='k', alpha=0.2)
  plt.scatter(ii, scores,
    color='g', s=20, alpha=0.3, marker="o")
  plt.scatter(jj, scores[scores >= threshold],
    color='r', s=20, alpha=0.7, marker="o")
  plt.scatter(kk, labels[labels==1],
    color='k', s=20, alpha=1.0, marker="+")
  plt.axis([0, len(labels), 0, 1.1])
  plt.title(relativePath)
  plt.show()
```

[image: here's the resulting plot]

Comment: i'm afraid you give too little info to answer your question, could you check what a single `plt.plot( ii, values)` gives you.

Comment: What's the shape of `ii` and `values`?  Are they 2D arrays? If so, `plot` interprets it differently (multiple lines) than it does for a 1D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the axes setting `plt.axis([0, len(labels), 0, 1.1])` because `values` does not fit in the y-axis bounds. So normalizing the `values` list keeps it within the specified bounds [0,1.1]. This is done with `norm_values = [float(v)/max(values) for v in values]`.